# What does `@SuppressWarnings("javadoc")` do? When is it Redundant?

Tags: java, javadoc, java-annotations

I have `@SuppressWarnings("javadoc")` on almost every class. My IDE gives me a warning on virtually all of them: "Redundant suppression".
I assume advances in technology have made this annotation obsolete, but
would like to understand what this annotation did in the first place. I could not find anything helpful. Apparently it suppresses compiles warnings, but I couldn't find anything on the argument "javadoc". And my code does compile, why would javadoc stand in the way of compiling anyway?

Answer (score 0):

`@SuppressWarnings("javadoc")` suppresses warnings about wrong javadoc, e.g. missing `@param` descriptions. An IDE will highlight such errors. This highlighting can be suppressed with `@SuppressWarnings("javadoc")`.
The annotation is redundant when there are no such errors in the javadoc of a class. If the annotation is not redundant and removed new warnings will show up detailing the javadoc errors.